# SharePoint 2016 Site Collection Web Analytics Reports Are Empty

Tags: sharepoint

I've spent the last 48hrs trying to troubleshoot this issue using the following resource:

https://swapnilkh.wordpress.com/troubleshoot-analytics-reports-issue-sharepoint-2013/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/spblog/sharepoint-2013-usage-analytics-the-story

http://www.sharepointtalk.net/2015/09/sharepoint-2016-beta-search-first-look.html

http://www.sharepointtalk.net/2013/06/powershell-for-sharepoint-2013.html

In our case, usage file are generated and the RequestUsage view is filled with up to date data in the Usage and Health DB. That said, the AnalyticsItemData table in the Search Service DB_AnalyticsReportingStore is empty.

From the troubleshooting I did, I was able to determine that both the 'Analytics Timer Job for Search Service Application' and the 'Usage Analytics Timer Job' never ran (LastRunTime: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM) event though they are enabled (Status: Online).

Trying to execute the following code:

```
$tj = Get-SPTimerJob -Type Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics.AnalyticsJobDefinition
$sa = $tj.GetAnalysis("Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics.SearchAnalyticsJob")
$sa.StartAnalysis()
```

Throws the following exception:

```
Exception calling "StartAnalysis" with "0" argument(s): "No such analysis exists: LinksStoreInput"
```

If I display Search Analytics Job status info:

```
$a = Get-SPTimerJob -Type Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics.AnalyticsJobDefinition
$sa = $a.GetAnalysis("Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics.SearchAnalyticsJob")
$sa.GetAnalysisInfo()
```

I can get this LastRunFailedErrorMsg:

```
Failed to prepare new analysis run: Unknown producer analysis LinksStoreInput
```

I couldn't find any information on the web related to these error messages.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.